# Fire, guns or lions?

Tags: situation

> A murderer is condemned to death.
>   He has to choose between three rooms.
>   The first is full of raging fires.
>   The second is full of assassins with loaded guns.
>   The third is full of lions that haven't eaten in 3 years.

**Which room is safest for him?**

(Didn't make it up myself, but thought you might like it)

Comment: This is a very old puzzle for kids. I am sure, someone would find a dupe for it...

Comment: oh my ... it would be better if you make it instead of using a old and known one

Comment: It probably would be, but I found it and thought it was a pretty neat one :(

Comment: So, starving to death is 'Safest'?, if all the result was death then I'll take the bullet #partypooper

Comment: I believe this is from 7 second riddles from instagram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously its

> The lions who hasn't eaten in three years as it would be dead by now

Comment: also I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate question somewhere

Comment: Wow, that sure was fast :S

Answer (score 4):

> He would open all the three doors at the same time , the lion would eat the all assassins and later  then the lion would jump into the fire , because of the guilt of killing so many people .It had turned into saint lion as it had fasted for 3 years. Then he can go any of the 2 rooms.

Comment: Upvoted for creativity :D

Comment: Better than the original and correct answer

Answer (score 4):

I think it's the

> Assasins

Let me first clarify a possible loophole in the typical answer:

> It could be disputed that "eating" is the process of inputing food in mouth, probably chewing, and then swallowing. There is an alternative: IV. So the lions could be alive without eating by having IVs on them.

If this is a case,

> Assasins are professionals and would generally not attack someone without reason.

Additionally,

> It sounds expensive for someone to gather *many* assasins in one room, full of guns, just to see the answer someone would give to a riddle. If this is NOT so, it means the assasins are there involuntarily. You would probably "free" them and have a bunch of armed assasins on your side to a common enemy...the bastard that plays games with people's lives. (Where's Minsc?)

On the other hand,

> It would be also expensive to being able to maintain a bunch of lions' IVs over 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> Lion, simply because they would be dead if they haven't eaten in 3 years.

Answer (score -2):

> I would go in the room of lions because the lions should be dead because they haven't eaten in three years.